# Database Design - Defining relationships between agreement terms with And / Or

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-schema

I will be designing a database over the next few months, and there is one problem on the horizon that I think will be a significant challenge.

How to track relationships between agreement terms and products using And / Or conditionals.

So what we are really interested in is the agreement a customer has on various products, and whether the agreements are concurrent or disjointed.

Some things to keep in mind

1) A single customer could have multiple agreements, covering various products.

2) A single agreement would look something like this (although they can get much more complex):

```
5 of Product-A AND 10 of Product-B OR 50 of Product-C OR $500 of Product-D
```

So the challenge for me is representing these varying and complex conditional agreements in a (hopefully somewhat) normalized structure.  This is going to be a production database and data integrity is crucial.

The data sources are upstream from this DB, and right now agreements are stored as a single row for each product/agreement combo `[AgreementID] - [Product] - [Terms]` .  However, if I can find a better method it may be migrated to the new database.

Has anyone ever face this kind of problem, or have any suggestions?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could design your schema like this:

Customers (CustomerID, Name)
Customer_Agreements (CustomerID, AgreementID, DateSigned)
Agreements (AgreementID, AgreementValidStart, AgreementValidEnd, Body)

Using a Point In Time schema design for your agreements table to see whether the agreement is current, or was valid in the past: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/.

Comment: To support Products you would then add a foreign key to the Customer_Agreements table relating to the Product Key.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and great resource.  I definitely think this is the right direction to solve this problem.  I am going to have to really think about how to implement it.  But if I understand correctly, I could have a record for a given product agreement, and then tie it to other records with an additional field `Operator` and another field `JoinedProduct`.  I don't know if I made this clear, but I am trying to model the agreement exactly as it is in plain spoken english.  So in my database I will know when the products are tied together like `20 of Prod1 AND 10 of Prod2 OR $100 Prod3`